# why "map update loop missed" warning occours and what are is effects?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am setting up a navigation as explained in [Navigation Stack Setup Tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup) stack for P3AT spawned. after making all the costmap files when **i run the move_base.launch file the following warning appears:-**

```
[ WARN] [1413658951.699133967]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 5.0000Hz... the loop actually took 2.1020 seconds
```

**I just want to know why this error occurs and what are its effects on automated navigation??**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/195281/why-%22map-update-loop-missed%22-warning-occours-and-what-are-is-effects??/) by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on ROS Answers with karma: 351 on 2014-10-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It means that your pc is attempting to update the map every 0.2 seconds (5 Hz), but it's actually taking 10x as long. This means you're likely saturating your system's processing capability, and need to reduce the load somewhere. The load could be coming from the costmap itself, from other costly operations such as SLAM, or just a limitation in your hardware.

From a practical point of view, it means that the costmap will have a 2 second delay before it contains data representing the latest sensor information.

To prevent the warning, you can go into the costmap's parameters, and reduce the update rate to something smaller.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on 2014-10-19**:
Thank you so much @paulbovbel, error has been removed. :)

**Comment by [vanquang](https://answers.ros.org/users/56332/vanquang/) on 2020-07-02**:
Hello @Aarif. How did you removed this error? I got it already

**Comment by [Aarif](https://answers.ros.org/users/20178/aarif/) on 2020-07-12**:
hi @vanquang, After banging my head for long, I wrote my own navigation program.

**Comment by [Kaveh_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/101393/kaveh_ros/) on 2022-10-20**:
Thanks.
It was my problem too, solved it this way:
changed the "update_frequency" from 5 to 2 in "costmap_common_params.yaml" file.